# Trouble Generating Pseudo 3D Road In PyGame - Iterating Through The Y & X Axis Runs Very Slow

Tags: python, pygame

**Summary:**
I'm trying to create a pseudo 3d race track in pygame by iterating over the y & x axis of the screen to colour the pixels individually. I can generate the track but the code runs very slow (0.5sec cycle) and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

**Details:**
Javidx9 did a retro race car tutorial in C++ (see link below) that I am trying to recreate in pygame but the code runs extremely slow when I try to emulate his 3d road solution using pygame.gfxdraw.pixel.

```
if x <= leftgrass:
   pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(gameDisplay, x, y, grass_color)
```

The track covers the bottom half of the screen and consists of several sections (left grass, left track clip, track, right track clip, right grass).

Comments on other posts suggested only updating specific sections of the background, but the program uses sine waves to create patterns of light and dark on the grass and the track to provide the illusion of movement.  So basically the entire track is always changing.

Is there a more efficient way I could achieve this effect?  It seems like modern computers should be able to handle a little game like this so I know the problem is with my inefficient code.

```
while not gameExit:

    for y in range(300, display_height):
        for x in range(0, display_width):

           '''Create race track and set perspective'''

            perspective = (y-300) / display_height
            middlepoint = 0.5
            roadwidth = (perspective + .01) * .8
            clipwidth = roadwidth * 0.15

            distance = 10 * time_passed(timestart)
            track_height = display_height / 2
            row = track_height + y

            '''Find x axis and widths of various parts of track'''
            (SNIP - just calculates the start & end x-points for the parts of the track). 


   
            '''color left grass'''
            if x <= leftgrass:
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(gameDisplay, x, y, grass_color)
            '''color left clip'''
            if x > leftgrass and x <= leftclip:
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(gameDisplay, x, y, clip_color)
            '''color road'''
            if x > leftclip and x <= rightclip:
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(gameDisplay, x, y, road_color)
            '''color right clip'''
            if x > rightclip and x <= rightgrass:
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(gameDisplay, x, y, clip_color)
            '''color right grass'''
            if x > rightgrass:
                pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(gameDisplay, x, y, grass_color)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

**Link To Source Video:**
Around the 6min mark he works on his race-track.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZI5Jbf18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the reality of python. You shouldn't do per pixel operations. If you really need to do that, use something like numba or cython to speed the process up.

---

In this specific case you only need to do something per y value operations. Python is fast enough for that (For a decent screen size, it is after all 1000 times less calculations per frame)

```
    middlepoint = 0.5
    distance = 10 * time_passed(timestart)
    track_height = display_height / 2

    for y in range(300, display_height):
        perspective = (y-300) / display_height
        roadwidth = (perspective + .01) * .8
        clipwidth = roadwidth * 0.15
        row = track_height + y

        '''Find x axis and widths of various parts of track'''
        (SNIP - just calculates the start & end x-points for the parts of the track). 

        pg.draw.line(screen, grass_color, (0, y), (leftgrass, y))
        pg.draw.line(screen, clip_color, (leftgrass, y), (leftclip, y))
        # ...
```

Also note than any constant operations should be pulled out of loops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I figured pixel operations would be pretty inefficient but wasn't sure if I was doing anything else wrong.  I'm just learning so I think maybe I will explore using image textures instead and try to transform them to provide a sense of perspective.